when you do pass by address, do you not need to 'always' pass a pointer?
In C language there are 2 ways to pass arguments to functions, right? One of them is Pass by address. Do you not need to always pass a pointer?
I haven't tried anything yet just wanted to know its logic/theory. I want to understand.

No. Calling foo(2) does not pass a pointer.

Think of it this way. It is up to you whether you pass-by-address (a pointer) or pass-by-value. There are a few subtleties involved, but when you pass by address you are passing an 8 byte (or 4-byte) address to something that can be many many times as big. So there are efficiency considerations as well. Passing a large structure by value requires a copy to be made of the entire thing. Now if passed by value and a copy is made -- you operate on the copy in the function. Any changes made are lost on function return unless you return a value. Pass by address allows modifying data at that address.

I’d love to be able to answer this question before it is closed by holy warriors.

I think it will likely be closed -- due to the fact there are dozens of duplicates directly on point. But, I'm with you, the more this can be addressed to help new C programmers cement the concept -- the better. (of course our Related list can never actually find the related posts...

I couldn’t find a good duplicate. I someone can it would be great.

Here is one What does pass-by value mean exactly in C? and I've got many more using "[c] pass by value pass by address" in the search up top.

I already saw that one, and don’t like it. It only produces a wall of text for answers, and does not care to suss out the concepts between pass-by-value and pass-by-pointer.

From the caller's point of view only, int ar[5]; foo(ar); works as a pass-by-reference, even if under the table, conversions occurred and foo() received a pass-by-value pointer.

Are there references in C? A post against the incorrect religious dogma "everything in C is passed by value".

All C parameters are "pass by value"
void fn (int i)
{
    /* You can change i in here but it's only working on a local copy of i
     */
}

void fn2(int* ip)
{
    /* You can change ip in here but it's only working on a local copy of ip.
     * If you change *ip then that will "stick" outside this function.
     */
}

/* sample calls */
int i=32;
fn(i);
fn2(&i);


Parameters aren't passed, arguments are passed. Either by value or by reference. If your example i is first passed by value and then by reference.

@Lundin it is really the personal taste of anyone to think of it as "i is passed by reference" or "the adress of i is passed by value".
I personally think the later brings less confusion to beginners, also considering that reference is a different concept in C++

Pass by value/reference are general terms above and beyond specific languages. No personal taste: either you pass a copy of the object or an address to it.

@Lundin i is first passed by value and then by reference  The actual argument in the second example isn't i, it's the address of i, which is passed by value.  The C compiler does not convert i to a reference (unlike a C++ compiler can), so explicit code is needed to take the address of i.  That's a "pass-by-reference" in the vernacular or non-technical words, but it isn't IMO "pass-by-reference" in a strict technical sense.

@AndrewHenle "it's the address of i, which is passed by value" Yeah but who cares? The programmer is only interested in passing the object by reference. What address it points at and how that address is passed along to the function is irrelevant for the program.

I'm so tired of these endless "there's only pass by value" on SO. It's as if someone is asking a question on how to best drive a car on a road and then a choir of pendants start screaming "You can't drive on the road, you drive on asphalt! Asphalt is a petrolium product and the result of refining raw oil-..."  Who cares! That's not what the question was about.

You have asked a holy war question.
The quick answer is that, in C, everything is passed by value. (And any other terminology is often considered anathema.)
Functions
When you invoke a function (or call it) you can “pass” it arguments to modify its behavior. This is called parameterization.

A formal argument is the name a function uses to refer to one of its parameterized values.
int square( int x )
{
    return x * x;
}

 ⟶ The name of this function is “square”.
⟶ The formal argument (there is only one argument for this function) is “x”.
⟶ The argument type is int.
⟶ In the body of the function we can use the formal argument name to refer to the actual integer value.

An actual argument is a value passed to the function when it is invoked.
printf( "%d\n", square(5) );

 ⟶ The actual argument to the function “square” is the value 5.
⟶ The type of the actual argument must match the type of the formal argument. As 5 is an int, it matches just fine.
We can use other objects to supply an actual argument value to a function, such as a variable named “number_of_birds”.
printf( "%d\n", square(number_of_birds) );

 ⟶ The actual argument to the function “square” is the integer value obtained from the variable object named “number_of_birds”.

In C, we often just say “argument” and let the context clue us into whether we are talking about the formal argument or actual argument.
Pass-by-value
An argument passed by value is one where the argument’s actual value is copied for use by the function — a new variable with the formal argument name is created and given the actual argument value.
This new variable only appears inside the specific invocation of the function: visible only to code in that function, and existing only in the time between the invocation and the return.
Using our example above, invoking square(5) would be very much like:
int square(...)
{
  int x = 5;
  return x * x;
}

Likewise, invoking square(-7) would be very much like:
int square(...)
{
  int x = -7;
  return x * x;
}

And again, as exampled above, the argument value need not be supplied by a literal constant. Another variable can be used to supply the actual argument value as well:
int number_of_birds = 2;
square(number_of_birds);

...which would be very much like writing:
int square(...)
{
  int x = number_of_birds;
  return x * x;
}

This is how all functions work in C: an actual argument value is supplied, and a copy of that value is made and given a name for use inside that function.
Pass-by-pointer
An object passed by pointer is one where a pointer to the object is passed as actual argument, not the object itself. The pointer itself is passed by value.
Inside the function, we have a new pointer variable, which can be dereferenced to access the object of interest.
void square( int * px )
{
  *px = (*px) * (*px);
}

 ⟶ The formal argument name is “px”.
⟶ The formal argument type is pointer to int.
⟶ In the function we dereference the pointer to access (and modify) the referenced value.
As you can see, this works like any other pointer in C, both in the function and when the function is invoked.
int x = 4;
square(&x);           // pass a pointer to x obtained with the & operator
printf( "%d\n", x );  // (prints 16)

int * q = &x;
square(q);            // pass q, which is already a pointer object
printf( "%d\n", x );  // (prints 256)


The reason we can say “pass-by-pointer” is that we may pragmatically consider the object parameterizing our function to be the thing addressed by the pointer value (rather than the pointer itself)!
C automatically does this to us when we try to pass arrays as argument:
int quuxify_array( int array[5] )

The array itself is not actually passed as argument. The syntax in this case is actually sugar for... a pointer!
int quuxify_array( int * array )

Yet we speak of “passing an array” to a function, when in reality we are just passing a pointer value. The object of interest isn’t the pointer, though. It is the array!
⟶ Conveniently, array[2] is fancy syntactic sugar for *(array+2). In other words, using the [ subscript/indexing ] operator is just a fancy way of dereferencing a pointer. Meaning, we could have written our square(int*) function as:
void square( int * px )
{
  px[0] = px[0] * px[0];
}


Pass-by-reference
In the C world, this is the same as pass-by-pointer.
A pointer value is an indirect reference to some object. (It is indirect because the value of a pointer is the address of the object, not the object itself.)
We dereference it to obtain direct access to the referenced object’s value. This is the only way in C to have an alias for another object.
In the C++ world, a reference is a direct reference, or alias, for another object, and does not need to be “dereferenced” via the * indirection operator. Using “references”, C++ users can have multiple aliases for a single object without need to wander through a pointer.
⟶ The way this actually works underneath is irrelevant. Unless you are writing a compiler, it doesn’t matter. No one asks how variable names work underneath either, but it is exactly the same kind of magic.
When you pass by address, must you always pass a pointer?
Finally, an answer (to the title text).
Yes. If the function takes as argument a pointer, then you must pass as argument a pointer. That is, the formal and actual argument types must match.
You can certainly do things to force a value to be a pointer, but that wouldn’t make any sense.
printf( "%s\n", (const char *)7 );  // segmentation fault mega ultra power GO!

The rest of this answer was because

[I] just wanted to know its logic/theory. I want to understand.

Holy Wars
Some people get really irritated when they see terms like pass-by-pointer. And they aren’t wrong. In C everything is passed by value. And you ought to know that.
But the terminology has been around for ages, and everyone knows what you mean.
If someone wants to give you a hard time about it, shrug it off. Actual professionals who do this all day every day don’t actually care enough to derail over this kind of ancient squabble. They know what you mean and will move on with their lives.
Whew. This was more than I signed in for.

"formal argument" is a deprecated term since C99.  "formal parameter" is not the preferred term (which was already used in C89).

And we usually simplify to just "argument" for the actual argument, and "parameter" for the formal parameter.

All function arguments are passed by value.  Sometimes that value is a pointer, which allows us to modify an object outside the function's scope:
void update( T *ptr )   // for any non-array object type T
{
  *ptr = new_T_value(); // writes a new value to the thing ptr points to
}

int main( void )
{
  T var;
  update( &var ); // writes a new value to var
}

ptr and var designate different objects in memory.  Updating ptr has no effect on var or vice-versa.  When we call update the expression &var is evaluated and its result (the address of the object var designates) is copied to ptr.  The expression *ptr acts as a sort-of alias for var; writing to *ptr is equivalent to writing to var.
 ptr == &var  // T * == T *
*ptr ==  var  // T   == T

We must use a pointer because the name var is not visible to update; the function cannot access the object directly by name, it can only access it indirectly through the pointer.
This is true if var is itself of pointer type.  Let's replace T with the pointer type P *:
void update( P **ptr )   
{
  *ptr = new_Pstar_value(); 
}

int main( void )
{
  P *var;
  update( &var ); 
}

The behavior is exactly the same.  ptr and var are still different objects in memory, ptr receives the result of &var, *ptr acts as an alias for var.  The only difference is the type.
Colloquially most C programmers will use "pass by reference" when they mean "pass a pointer by value".  Even though it isn't true pass-by-reference, the intent is to mimic pass-by-reference semantics.
Where things get weird is with arrays (and string literals, which are arrays under the hood); under most circumstances, array expressions "decay" to pointers to their first element.  When you pass an array as a function argument:
int arr[10];
...
foo( arr );

what the function actually receives is a pointer value equivalent to &arr[0]:
void foo( int *a ) { ... }

The mechanism is still pass by value (a is a distinct object that gets a copy of arr's value), it's just that the value of an array expression is a pointer.  Yes it's confusing and a bit of a pain in the ass.
Another reason to pass a pointer instead of a value is if you're dealing with a large struct type, such that the overhead of copying all that data is enough to impact performance.  In that case we'll often pass a pointer, although to be safe we may const-qualify it:
void foo( const struct huge *ptr )
{
  ...
}

so that we don't accidentally update the contents of whatever it's pointing to.

There are two primary ways to pass arguments to functions:
Pass By Value: A copy of the argument's value is passed to the function. Changes made within the function don't affect the original variable. This is the default method in C and is simple but can be inefficient for large data structures since a full copy is made.
Use pass by value when you only need to read the argument's value without modifying the original variable.
void func1_swap(int x, int y) {
  int temp = x;
  x=y;
  y= temp;
}

Pass By Reference: The memory reference of the argument is passed to the function using a pointer. This allows the function to modify the original variable directly and is more efficient for large data structures because only the address is passed. However, it requires careful handling to avoid unintended side effects.
Use pass by address/reference (pointers) when you need to modify the original variable or handle large data structures efficiently.
void func2_swap(int *x, int *y) {
  int temp = *x;
  *x=*y;
  *y= temp;
}

if a=10, b=20
when you call func1_swap(a,b), it will swap a value and b value internally, but original variables won't effect
when you call func2_swap(&a,&b), it will swap a value and b value internally, but original variables also will be swapped.

C only has "pass by value". You can do something similar to "pass by reference" by passing the value of a pointer but C doesn't actually have "pass by reference".

@John3136 And yet “pass by reference” has been a common term since before C was invented.

@Dúthomhas Right, because some languages that do use it, like Fortran, are older than C.  But C only has pass-by-value.  You can simulate pass-by-reference in C by explicitly passing a pointer, but that pointer is passed by value, not by reference.

@TomKarzes ...and because it is entirely reasonable to call passing a pointer to an object “pass by pointer” — my function works on an object, and I don’t think it is reasonable to have to always be super pedantic and say “I’m passing a pointer to my object so my function can dereference said pointer to modify the object.”

The "subtleties" are "pass by address" (or reference) is a lot cleaner for explaining the concept as opposed to "passing a pointer by value" or "passing the address of a pointer by value" -- their eyes have already rolled back in their head at that point. Common terms, pass-by-value and pass-by-address (or reference). You are either passing "the thing" itself or the "address of the thing" -- the fact that "the thing" can already be a pointer simply goes to understanding what "the thing" is to begin with.

@DavidC.Rankin That’s pretty much my point. The object we are parameterizing over is not the pointer, but the thing referenced by the pointer’s value. Quibbling over the term just makes a mountain out of it when the meaning has always been clear enough.

I'll second that, which was what I intended.

@Dúthomhas If it's confined to C, there isn't much room for confusion, but when applied to other languages that have both pointers and by-reference arguments, mixing the terms leads to a lot of confusion.  In true pass-by-reference, modifying a parameter in a function changes the variable that was passed.  That never happens in C.  It's more than just being pedantic.  It's a very real difference.

@TomKarzes: C programmers are not responsible for avoiding confusion in other languages. This is older than FORTRAN; it stems from assembly, where it is only possible to pass whatever the programmer specifies, but things were nonetheless passed by address, that being the address the programmer manually provided to refer to a thing. C++ created confusion by adopting the term “reference” to mean a new thing that the compiler handled automatically. C programmers are not obligated to give up their prior terminology as if C++ had a right to take it away from them…

… Manually passing a reference is still passing a reference.

@John3136: Re “C only has "pass by value"”: No, this is false. C has only automatically pass by value. The programmer may manually construct pass by reference in C by passing an address. The term “pass by reference” was historically used to mean passing a thing by passing its address, even when that address argument was manually constructed. C++ created or added to confusion by using the old term “reference” in a new way, so some people want to use it only to refer to when the compiler automatically passes an address. But the prior meaning of the term remains, and you can do it in C.

@EricPostpischil When someone says a language has pass-by-reference, they're talking about what the language directly supports.  It's a programming language term. They aren't talking about how you can manually craft it yourself using pointers.  For a language to have pass-by-reference, it means that you can pass a variable to a function, and if that function modifies the corresponding formal parameter, the variable that the caller passed will also change.  There are different strategies for implementing this, but they generally involve the caller passing a pointer.  C doesn't do this.

@EricPostpischil Regarding assembly language, it doesn't have any calling convention.  It's left entirely up to the programmer.  C has pass-by-value.  Python has pass-by-value.  Fortran has pass-by-reference.  Algol has call-by-name.  Some languages support multiple argument passing strategies.  C isn't one of them.  C provides pass-by-value, period.  The programmer can use that to pass pointers to things, and it may even be compatible with, say, the calling sequence of a Fortran compiler, but on the C end, it's still pass-by-value.

@TomKarzes: Re “Regarding assembly language, it doesn't have any calling convention”: No, different programmers have to coordinate, and assembly source code has to follow the interface rules when it interfaces with other software. In any case, providing access to an object by passing its address was called pass-by-reference. That was a thing before it was built into languages automatically, and it remains a thing. People used English that way, they still use English that way, and they are not wrong to do so. Passing by reference manually is passing by reference.

@TomKarzes I don't read Eric's comments as claiming C directly supports pass-by-reference.  I read them as a description of the vernacular use of "pass by reference" where the programmer has to manually construct pass-by-reference around C's strict pass-by-value semantics.  I don't read it as a technical, precise desription saying that C has pass-by-reference as a fundamental feature like FORTRAN does.
